# UDP socket in cpp loops for ever

Tags: c++, multithreading, udp, tcpclient, udpclient

I had a code that implemented several threads in c++ and it worked fine. One of those threads is a UDP server that receives messages from a UDP client. So for so good.

Now I wanted to implement a TCP server on a different thread so both a UDP client and a TCP client would be able to send messages to its proper server (they are running on different ports). After doing this, the UDP server would go nuts ... (I really do not know how to explain nuts). Please, try to follow me:

Minimal Code:

```
// How to compile using mysql.h
// g++ -o aserver aserver.cpp $(mysql_config --libs) -lpthread
//
//// to operate with I/O functions
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
// to operate with strings
#include <string>
// to operate with string streams
#include <sstream>
// to opereta with time
#include <time.h>
// to operate with directories
#include <dirent.h>
// to operate with sleep function
#include <unistd.h>
// to operate with threads
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
// to operate with sockets
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
// Defines the structure of the socket
#include <netinet/in.h>
// Uses memset to clear the structure
#include <string.h>
#include <cerrno>

using namespace std;

// **************************************************************
// * GLOBAL VARIABLES                                           *
// **************************************************************
int logto_id;
int udp_port;
int tcp_port;
int sock;

const int success = 0;
const int general_error = -1;
const string general_error_str = "Error";

void logto(string text, int debug_id) {

    int append_status;

    switch (debug_id) {
    case 1:
        cout << text + "\n";
        break;
    case 2:
        break;
    case 3:
        break;
    default:
        cout << "";
    }

}

int create_udp_socket() {

    // UDP Socket Variables
    unsigned int serverlen;
    sockaddr_in udpServer;
    int bind_status = 0;

    string function_name="create_udp_socket: ";

    /* Create the UDP socket */
    sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
    if (sock < 0) {
        cout << function_name + "Could not create UDP socket...\n";
        return general_error;
    }

    /* Construct the server sockaddr_in structure */
    memset(&udpServer, 0, sizeof(udpServer));       /* Clear struct */
    udpServer.sin_family = AF_INET;                 /* Internet/IP */
    udpServer.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);  /* Any IP address */
    udpServer.sin_port = htons(udp_port);           /* server port */

    /* Bind the socket */
    serverlen = sizeof(udpServer);
    bind_status= bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &udpServer, serverlen);
    if (bind_status < 0) {
        cout << function_name + "Could not bind UDP socket...\n";
        return general_error;
    } else {
        cout << function_name + "UDP Socket created and binded...\n";
        return success;
    }

}

int create_tcp_socket() {

    // TCP Socket Variables
    unsigned int serverlen;
    sockaddr_in tcpServer;
    int bind_status = 0;
    int listen_status = 0;

    string function_name="create_tcp_socket: ";

    /* Create the TCP socket */
    sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (sock < 0) {
        cout << function_name + "Could not create TCP socket...\n";
        return general_error;
    }

    /* Construct the server sockaddr_in structure */
    memset(&tcpServer, 0, sizeof(tcpServer));       /* Clear struct */
    tcpServer.sin_family = AF_INET;                 /* Internet/IP */
    tcpServer.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);  /* Any IP address */
    tcpServer.sin_port = htons(tcp_port);           /* server port */

    /* Bind the socket */
    serverlen = sizeof(tcpServer);
    bind_status = bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &tcpServer, serverlen);
    if (bind_status < 0) {
        cout << function_name + "Could not bind TCP socket...\n";
        return general_error;
    } else {
        cout << function_name + "TCP Socket created and binded...\n";

        /* Listen */
        listen_status = listen(sock,10);
        if (listen_status < 0) {
            cout << function_name + "Could not listen on the TCP socket...\n";
            return general_error;
        } else {
            cout << function_name + "TCP Socket listening...\n";
            return success;
        }

    }

}

void *thread_udp_server(void *arg) {
    // **************************************************************
    // * LOCAL VARIABLES                                            *
    // * we define this internal variables that before were Global  *
    // **************************************************************

    /* here we store the SQL INSERT query */
    string node_query;
    /* here we find the data to build the query 
     * this variable is always passed by reference to all the functions
     */
    string node_line;
    /* UDP Socket related variables */
    char udp_buffer[255];
    int received = 0;
    unsigned int echolen, clientlen;
    sockaddr_in udpClient;

    // Name of thread
    string thread_name = (char*)arg;

    // We start the whole thing ...
    if (create_udp_socket()==success) {

        /* Endless loop */
        //for(;;) {
        while(1) {
            logto(udp_buffer,logto_id);
            /* Receive a message from the client */
            clientlen = sizeof(udpClient);
            received = recvfrom(sock, udp_buffer, 255, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &udpClient, &clientlen);

            if (received < 0) {

                logto(thread_name + " Failed to receive message",logto_id);
                std::cout << "Something went wrong! errno " << errno << ": ";
                std::cout << strerror(errno) << std::endl;

            } else {

                logto("\n---------\n" + thread_name,logto_id);
                /* We now copy the content of the buffer into 'node_line' */
                node_line=udp_buffer;

                logto(thread_name + node_line,logto_id);

            }

        }

    } else {

        logto(thread_name + " Could not bring up UDP socket...",logto_id);
        std::cout << "Something went wrong! errno " << errno << ": ";
        std::cout << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
        return NULL;

    }

}

void *thread_tcp_server(void *arg) {
    // **************************************************************
    // * LOCAL VARIABLES                                            *
    // * we define this internal variables that before were Global  *
    // **************************************************************

    /* here we store the SQL INSERT query */
    string node_query;
    /* here we find the data to build the query 
     * this variable is always passed by reference to all the functions
     */
    string node_line;
    /* TCP Socket related variables */
    char tcp_buffer[255];
    int recTcp = 0;
    unsigned int echolen, clientlen;
    sockaddr_in tcpClient;

    // Name of thread
    string thread_name = (char*)arg;

    // We start the whole thing ...
    if (create_tcp_socket()==success) {

        /* Endless loop */
        for(;;) {
            logto(tcp_buffer,logto_id);
            /* Receive a message from the client */
            clientlen = sizeof(tcpClient);
            recTcp = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &tcpClient, &clientlen);
            if (recTcp < 0) {

                logto(thread_name + " Failed to receive message",logto_id);
                std::cout << "Something went wrong! errno " << errno << ": ";
                std::cout << strerror(errno) << std::endl;

            } else {

                logto("\n---------\n" + thread_name,logto_id);
                /* We now copy the content of the buffer into 'node_line' */
                node_line=tcp_buffer;

                logto(thread_name + node_line,logto_id);

            }

        }

    } else {

        logto(thread_name + " Could not bring up TCP socket...",logto_id);
        std::cout << "Something went wrong! errno " << errno << ": ";
        std::cout << strerror(errno) << std::endl;

        return NULL;

    }

}

// -----------------
// - main function -
// -----------------
int main () {

    // **************************************************************
    // * VARIABLES                                          *
    // **************************************************************

    // Labels of the threads
    string label_udp = "UDP_thread";
    string label_tcp = "TCP_thread";

    // We define the threads...
    pthread_t udp_server_id=20;
    pthread_t tcp_server_id=50;

    udp_port = 10101;
    tcp_port = 10102;
    logto_id = 1;

    // **************************************************************
    // * START                                                      *
    // **************************************************************

    if ( pthread_create( &udp_server_id, NULL, thread_udp_server, (void*) label_udp.c_str()) ) {
        logto("Error creating thread_udp_server...",logto_id);
        return general_error;
    }

    if ( pthread_create( &tcp_server_id, NULL, thread_tcp_server, (void*) label_tcp.c_str()) ) {
        logto("Error creating thread_tcp_server...",logto_id);
        return general_error;
    }

    if ( pthread_join ( udp_server_id, NULL ) ) {
        logto("UDP_thread couldn't join the main thread...",logto_id);
        return general_error;
    }

    if ( pthread_join ( tcp_server_id, NULL ) ) {
        logto("TCP_thread couldn't join the main thread...",logto_id);
        return general_error;
    }

}
```

After starting the program, the errno are the following, depending on which socket were brought up:

TCP ok!:

```
./aserver
create_tcp_socket: TCP Socket created and binded...
create_tcp_socket: TCP Socket listening...

create_udp_socket: Could not bind UDP socket...
UDP_thread Could not bring up UDP socket...
Something went wrong! errno 22: Invalid argument
```

UDP ok!:

```
./aserver
create_udp_socket: UDP Socket created and binded...
create_tcp_socket: TCP Socket created and binded...
create_tcp_socket: Could not listen on the TCP socket...
TCP_thread Could not bring up TCP socket...
Something went wrong! errno 95: Operation not supported
```

There is also a third case, where the UDP is brough up (the TCP socket remains down) and for some reasing, I get these messages scrolling all along the window...

```
./aserver
create_tcp_socket: Could not bind TCP socket...
TCP_thread Could not bring up TCP socket...
Something went wrong! errno create_udp_socket: UDP Socket created and binded...

22: UDP_thread Failed to receive message
Something went wrong! errno 107: Transport endpoint is not connectedInvalid argument

UDP_thread Failed to receive message
Something went wrong! errno 107: Transport endpoint is not connected

UDP_thread Failed to receive message
Something went wrong! errno 107: Transport endpoint is not connected

UDP_thread Failed to receive message
Something went wrong! errno 107: Transport endpoint is not connected
```

However, if I comment out either thread (TCP or UDP) the remaining one works ok ...

**Bottom line: I cannot get both threads (UDP and TCP) to live together at the same time...**

Could anyone give me a hint on this. I'm really lost on why both threads at the same time break my application ... :-(

Thanks in advance,

Lucas

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) demonstrating the problem in action. When you create both sockets, you are probably trashing something, but we can't see that in the code you have shown. And also, when socket functions fail you should log the error codes they report. That will tell you why they failed. You can get the error codes from `errno` (or `WSAGetLastError()` on Windows).

Comment: It has been a few years since I've worked with programming a server & client application that can use either TCP or UDP. I'm not 100% sure because it has been so long, but I think it has to do with the port addressing that they use through the winsock lib down to the actual hardware. I'm not sure if you can have both running at the same time, unless if you are explicitly specifying different ports for each type, which you state that they are, also your server and client has to match between TCP or UDP. So I think this could be an implementation problem not seen here.

Comment: Another thing that you have to worry about is that your written application may be working correctly but if you are running this on the same machine or over a lan, through firewalls there is quite a bit of setup to get them to communicate with each other. You might have to allow specific ports through the firewall, you may have to configure routers for port forwarding and port triggering etc. Keep these things in mind!

Comment: Hi @RemyLebeau, understood. Sorry for the snipets, but then: what's the best way of providing the MCV example? Code is quite big ... :-( ... I'll try to remove the extras so to provide something that can work out ... by the way, I'm working on Linux (no Windows here) ...

Comment: Hi @FrancisCugler, thanks for the reply. Indeed, the ports are different, which, in my opinion it would be a problem since the protocol is differente `(sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);` vs `sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);)`... but eventhoug using different ports, I cannot get both sockets to be up and running...

Comment: Hi @RemyLebeau, I've uploaded a minimal working code that reproduces the error that I'm facing. Please look at [link](http://www.filedropper.com/server).There are two files in it: `aserver.cpp` and `server_threads.h`. Don't know if this is enough ... Any feedback will be very appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: @LucasAimaretto: please don't ask people to download code from external sites. If the code is too large to put in your question directly, it is not minimal enough. While you work on that, let's start with something simple - what error code is `errno` actually reporting when `recvfrom()` fails?

Comment: Hi @RemyLebeau, I've modified the post, providing a minimal code and some examples where you can get to see the errno depending on the working thread. When UDP is up, TCP shows `errno 95: Operation not supported`. When TCP is ok, UDP shows `errno 22: Invalid argument`. Finally, when UDP goes nuts (after the `recvfrom()`), I get `errno 107: Transport endpoint is not connected`. Thanks for your help and hints (I didn't realize about the errno before!!)

Comment: You have a **major** problem with your error reporting. `errno` can change with every system call. *Ergo* when a system call returns -1, the *first* thing you must do is report `errno`. That should be in your `logto()` method. Every time you've printed with `errno`, the value and the message are suspect. Try it again with correct error-handling code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are using the same, global socket for the two threads.

```
int sock;
```

If the `create_udp_socket` function runs first, the socket that it creates will get overwritten by `create_tcp_socket`, and vice versa.

Possible solutions, either use two global sockets:

```
int tcp_sock;
int udp_sock;
```

or (better) make the `create_xxx_socket` functions return the sockets directly to the callers, avoiding the use of global variables.

Here's an example of the latter (error handling omitted for clarity).

```
int create_tcp_socket()
{
    int sock;

    /* Create the TCP socket */
    sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    /* Bind and listen... */

    return sock;
}
```

The TCP thread would call `create_tcp_socket` like this.

```
void *thread_tcp_server(void *arg)
{
    /* ... */

    int sock = create_tcp_socket();
    if(sock < 0)
    {
        logto(thread_name + " Could not bring up TCP socket...", logto_id);
        return NULL;
    }

    /* Socket created, start accept'ing connections */
}
```

Global variables are bad for a number of reasons.

In multithreaded code particularly, keeping data (`sock` in this case) private means there is less doubt about *ownership*.

The code might make assumptions about who owns a global variable, but as programs grow in size this becomes impossible to manage in practice.

Contrast this with returning `sock` from one of the creation methods; It is easy to see that initially, `sock` is owned by the creation method. When the creation method returns, ownership of the socket is passed to the caller. There is never more than one function or thread with access to the socket, so concurrent access to the socket is never an issue.

Knowing who owns the data also makes it easier to release or deallocate resources when they are no longer needed. In this case, if a server thread were to exit, it - being the owner of the socket - would be responsible for closing it on its way out. And it can do so safely because no-one else could be using the socket.

Comment: Hi @Carsten, thanks for the tip. It's so obvious and I did not see it. Thanks for clarifying it. Now, I understand the use of both the variables (int tcp_sock and udp_sock). I think, also, that I get your idea of making the functions return the sockets -conceptually- but really do not know how to implement it ... do you have an example or at least a link where to read something? By the way, I tried using both the global variables and that solved my problem! Thanks!!

Comment: Lucas, that's great to hear. I've updated my answer to show how to return a socket from the creation methods

Comment: Hi @Carsten, just to mention I did try your suggestions (returning the socket to the caller) and it's working like a charm ...thanks. And I agree with you: not only is more elegant this way, it's also simpler and safer. Thanks for the tip! Lucas